# Fade in boxes 1 after the other with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make a 'blanket' of divs containing child divs 150px high and 150px wide.

I want each child div to fade in 1 after the other after after a millisecond or so, opacity changing from 0, to 1.

I cant seem to figure out how this works, or how id do it though?

http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var figure = [];
    w = 1500;
    h = 450;
    for(i = 0, i < 30, i++){
        $('div').append(figure[].clone()).fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: You want to clone an array? This is what is showing your code here. BTW, provide relevant html code in your jsfiddle

Comment: you're using the figure tag which is HTML5 specific, so I'm assuming you're going to use CSS3. Going with that assumption you can do animations with CSS3 which doesn't require any javascript.

Comment: have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/4/ then add into it the ability to use `setTimeout()` and you should eb good to go, didnt have time to finish it off sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution.

The problems in your code

- in `for(i = 0, i < 30, i++)`, you should use ';', not ',' . Use developer tools in your browser to catch such typos
- In your code `$('div').append(figure[].clone()).fadeIn();` , The `fadeIn` applies to $('div') as append() returns the calling object itself. You must replace it with `$('<figure></figure>').appendTo('div').fadeIn('slow');` and to fadeIn items one by one you could set a timeout with incrementing delays
- Add `display: none;` style to the figure to keep it hidden initially

Here is the full code.

```
$(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        setTimeout(function(){$('<figure></figure>').appendTo('div').fadeIn('slow');}, i*200);
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle to see it working http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/12/

Answer (score 1):

Try using greensock TweenLite http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/. 
It has staggerTo/staggerFrom action that does exactly what you are asking. TweenLite in conjunction with jQuery makes animation very easy.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a possible solution ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/2/)).

Use an immediate function and call it again *n* times in the fadeIn callback.

```
$(function(){
    var figure = $('figure');

    var counter = 0;
    (function nextFade() {
        counter++;
        figure.clone().appendTo('div').hide().fadeIn(500, function() {
            if(counter < 30) nextFade();
        });
    })();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following implementation as an example. Using `setTimeout()` will do the trick.

I've updated your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  var delay = 100;

  for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var new_box = box.clone();
      $('.container').append(new_box);
      new_box.fadeIn();
    }, delay);

    delay += 500; // Delay the next box by an extra 500ms
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order for the element to actually fade in, it must be hidden in the first place, i.e. `display: none;` or `.hide()`

Here's perhaps a more robust solution without counters:
http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/6/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    $('div').append($('<figure>figure</figure>'));
}

(function fade(figure, duration) {
    if (figure) 
        figure.fadeIn(duration, function() { fade(figure.next(), duration); });
})($('figure').first(), 400);
```

By the way, clauses in for loops are separated using semicolons, not commas.